# Mocking of celery worker gives authentication error

Tags: mocking, celery, celery-task

I am following documentation for the [celery testing](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html#celery-worker-embed-live-worker) to test my celery task.

I also using `PyTest-bdd` for BDD testing.

My project structure are as below

```
myprj/
├── __init__.py
├── app
│   └── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── features
│   │   └── automation
│   │       └── core
│   │           └── celerytasks.feature
│   └── functional
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── automation
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── conftest.py
│           └── core
│               ├── __init__.py
│               └── test_celerytasks.py
├── tox-requirements.txt
└── tox.ini
```

**myprj/requirements.txt**

```
amqp==2.4.2
billiard==3.6.0.0
celery==4.3.0
kombu==4.5.0
vine==1.3.0
```

**myprj/tox-requirements.txt**

```
coverage>=4.1
flake8
pylint
pytest-cov==2.6.1
pytest==4.4.0
pytest-bdd
pytest-flask
pytest-mock
pytest-xdist
```

**myprj/tox.ini**

```
[tox]
envlist = functional,lint
skipsdist = True
sitepackages = False
skip_missing_interpreters = True

[testenv]
basepython=python3.5
deps=
    -rtox-requirements.txt
    -rrequirements.txt

install_command = pip install -i https://pypi.mydomain.com --extra-index-url https://pypi.mydomain.com --trusted-host pypi.mydomain.com {opts} {packages} --exists-action w

setenv = FLASK_CONFIG=testing

[testenv:functional]
commands=
    py.test -n auto -l --cov=app --cov-report term-missing --no-cov-on-fail --max-slave-restart=0 tests/functional/

[testenv:lint]
commands=pylint app
```

**myprj/tests/features/automation/core/celerytasks.feature**

```
@automation @celerytasks

Feature: Get core device details
  Get the core details for device


Scenario: Valid device number with argument string
    Given valid device number as deviceNumbers
    When enter the deviceNumbers "123456" with attributes "name"
    Then it should return "mydevicename"
```

**myprj/tests/functional/automation/conftest.py**

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_config():
    return {
        'broker_url': 'amqp://',
        'result_backend': 'redis://'
    }


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_enable_logging():
    return True
```

**myprj/tests/functional/automation/core/test_celerytasks.py**

```
import pytest

from pytest_bdd import when
from pytest_bdd import then
from pytest_bdd import given
from pytest_bdd import parsers
from pytest_bdd import scenario


@scenario("../../../features/automation/core/celerytasks.feature",
        "Valid device number with argument string")
def test_celerytasks(celery_worker):
    pass


@given("valid device number as deviceNumbers")
def context():
    return {}

@when(parsers.parse('enter the deviceNumbers "{deviceNumbers:d}"'
                    ' with attributes "{attributes}"'))
def set_data(deviceNumbers, attributes, context):
    context['deviceNumbers'] = deviceNumbers
    context['attributes'] = attributes


@pytest.mark.celery
@then(parsers.parse('it should return "{result}"'))
def get_results(result, context, celery_worker):
    print(context)
```

When I run that using tox, it gives error for Authentication.

```
$ tox -e functional
functional create: /Users/myuser/myprj/.tox/functional
functional installdeps: -rtox-requirements.txt, -rrequirements.txt
functional installed: amqp==2.4.2,apipkg==1.4,astroid==1.6.2,atomicwrites==1.3.0,attrs==19.1.0,billiard==3.6.0.0,celery==4.3.0,click==6.7,coverage==4.5.2,execnet==1.5.0,flake8==3.5.0,Flask==1.0.2,glob2==0.6,isort==4.3.4,itsdangerous==0.24,Jinja2==2.10,kombu==4.5.0,lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1,Mako==1.0.9,MarkupSafe==1.0,mccabe==0.6.1,more-itertools==7.0.0,parse==1.12.0,parse-type==0.4.2,pathlib2==2.3.3,pluggy==0.11.0,py==1.8.0,pycodestyle==2.3.1,pyflakes==1.6.0,pylint==1.8.3,pytest==4.4.0,pytest-bdd==3.1.0,pytest-cov==2.6.1,pytest-flask==0.10.0,pytest-forked==0.2,pytest-mock==1.7.1,pytest-xdist==1.22.2,pytz==2019.1,six==1.12.0,vine==1.3.0,Werkzeug==0.14.1,wrapt==1.10.11
functional run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='4168571602'
functional run-test: commands[0] | py.test -n auto -l --cov=app --cov-report term-missing --no-cov-on-fail --max-slave-restart=0 tests/functional/
=============================================================================================== test session starts ================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-4.4.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.11.0
cachedir: .tox/functional/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/myuser/myprj
plugins: xdist-1.22.2, mock-1.7.1, forked-0.2, flask-0.10.0, cov-2.6.1, bdd-3.1.0, celery-4.3.0
gw0 [1] / gw1 [1] / gw2 [1] / gw3 [1] / gw4 [1] / gw5 [1] / gw6 [1] / gw7 [1]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
E                                                                                                                                                                                                            [100%]Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)

====================================================================================================== ERRORS ======================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_celerytasks ________________________________________________________________________________________
[gw5] darwin -- Python 3.5.2 /Users/myuser/myprj/.tox/functional/bin/python3.5

request = <SubRequest 'celery_worker' for <Function test_celerytasks>>, celery_app = <Celery celery.tests at 0x10c6a03c8>, celery_includes = (), celery_worker_pool = 'solo', celery_worker_parameters = {}

    @pytest.fixture()
    def celery_worker(request,
                      celery_app,
                      celery_includes,
                      celery_worker_pool,
                      celery_worker_parameters):
        # type: (Any, Celery, Sequence[str], str) -> WorkController
        """Fixture: Start worker in a thread, stop it when the test returns."""
        if not NO_WORKER:
            for module in celery_includes:
                celery_app.loader.import_task_module(module)
            with worker.start_worker(celery_app,
                                     pool=celery_worker_pool,
>                                    **celery_worker_parameters) as w:

celery_app = <Celery celery.tests at 0x10c6a03c8>
celery_includes = ()
celery_worker_parameters = {}
celery_worker_pool = 'solo'
request    = <SubRequest 'celery_worker' for <Function test_celerytasks>>

.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/contrib/pytest.py:176:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py:59: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/contrib/testing/worker.py:78: in start_worker
    **kwargs) as worker:
../.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py:59: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/contrib/testing/worker.py:106: in _start_worker_thread
    conn.default_channel.queue_declare
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py:852: in default_channel
    self.ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py:422: in ensure_connection
    callback, timeout=timeout)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py:341: in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py:275: in connect
    return self.connection
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py:823: in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py:778: in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py:130: in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py:313: in connect
    self.drain_events(timeout=self.connect_timeout)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py:500: in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py:506: in blocking_read
    return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py:55: in on_frame
    callback(channel, method_sig, buf, None)
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py:510: in on_inbound_method
    method_sig, payload, content,
.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py:126: in dispatch_method
    listener(*args)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <kombu.transport.pyamqp.Connection object at 0x10c75ada0>, reply_code = 403, reply_text = 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'
class_id = 0, method_id = 0

    def _on_close(self, reply_code, reply_text, class_id, method_id):
        """Request a connection close.

        This method indicates that the sender wants to close the
        connection. This may be due to internal conditions (e.g. a
        forced shut-down) or due to an error handling a specific
        method, i.e. an exception.  When a close is due to an
        exception, the sender provides the class and method id of the
        method which caused the exception.

        RULE:

            After sending this method any received method except the
            Close-OK method MUST be discarded.

        RULE:

            The peer sending this method MAY use a counter or timeout
            to detect failure of the other peer to respond correctly
            with the Close-OK method.

        RULE:

            When a server receives the Close method from a client it
            MUST delete all server-side resources associated with the
            client's context.  A client CANNOT reconnect to a context
            after sending or receiving a Close method.

        PARAMETERS:
            reply_code: short

                The reply code. The AMQ reply codes are defined in AMQ
                RFC 011.

            reply_text: shortstr

                The localised reply text.  This text can be logged as an
                aid to resolving issues.

            class_id: short

                failing method class

                When the close is provoked by a method exception, this
                is the class of the method.

            method_id: short

                failing method ID

                When the close is provoked by a method exception, this
                is the ID of the method.
        """
        self._x_close_ok()
        raise error_for_code(reply_code, reply_text,
>                            (class_id, method_id), ConnectionError)
E       amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

class_id   = 0
method_id  = 0
reply_code = 403
reply_text = 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'
self       = <kombu.transport.pyamqp.Connection object at 0x10c75ada0>

.tox/functional/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py:639: AccessRefused
============================================================================================= 1 error in 3.26 seconds ==============================================================================================
ERROR: InvocationError for command /Users/myuser/myprj/.tox/functional/bin/py.test -n auto -l --cov=app --cov-report term-missing --no-cov-on-fail --max-slave-restart=0 tests/functional/ (exited with code 1)
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary ______________________________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   functional: commands failed
```

As we mock the config for the celery, I don't know why its giving authentication error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like under your conftest.py you didn't configure your broker/backend so there the celery connection fails. This is what worked for me.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def celery_config(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker,request):
with django_db_blocker.unblock():

    return {
        'broker_url': 'redis://localhost:6379',
        'result_backend': 'redis://localhost:6379'
    }
```

Comment: Aaron, I already configure that using `'broker_url': 'amqp://',`